# Can I edit MP3 tags on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: 8.0, music

Is it possible to edit MP3 tags for songs in the library on a WP8 phone?

I currently have a WP 7.5 phone and it doesn't seem possible to do so on there, so alternatively: Is there an app which supports this? Ideally, the updated info would then sync back to the PC library via zune.

Comment: Your question title mention WP8, your question mention WP7 too and you added both tags. Can you clarify your question? Looks like you really want solve a problem with WP7. The answer for both versions probably will be different since they sync different.

Answer (score 2):

The name of this is [ID3 tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3).

You can edit ID3 tags of mp3 files with Windows Phone 8.

I found at least two options: [Mu5ic Download5](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mu5ic-download5/b3c030c4-3473-4c4b-a0f1-6caa15d0d6a1) and [Download5](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/download5/3cf74db4-f3ec-4f7e-ba6f-1aaef3526ff2)

I can't find one for Windows Phone 7.5 but you can do this directly in Zune before send it to the phone.

Comment: Does it sync changes back to the source?

Comment: I didn't try the apps. Just made a search for the term ID3 tag and both claim can edit those informations.

Answer (score 0):

I found an even better one called Music Import http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=195ebeaa-95ae-4876-81b9-a463098d42de it finds a load more songs than Mp3 Finder too!

Answer (score -1):

If you have a computer or laptop and a USB cord you can go to file explorer and click windows phone then open the music file and start renaming this is one of the easiest way for me.